# How to access a combobox text of the form1 from another user control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a project that contains multiple pages in the same window and i made that using multiple User Controls docked on top of each other and when you click the page button it shows up using: `userControl1.Show();` / `userControl1.Hide();`.
I'm facing some problems when i try to access a `combobox` text that is located on the `form1`, i have tried using public strings such as:

```
public string comPort;
private void cbPort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comPort = cbPort.Text;
}
```

and trying to access it from the other user control using:

```
Form1 mainForm;
public FiremwareFlasher()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mainForm = (Form1)this.FindForm();
}
```

and then:

```
MessageBox.Show(mainForm.comPort);
```

But i got that error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making cmdPort as `static` and accessing directly with `Form1.cmdPort`?

Comment: @Aadittya oh thanks, it works, now is there a better solution to access controls such as buttons and textbox directly like using Form1.button1?

Comment: Why do you need Form1.button1 here? Do you need the button instance or you need some property belonging to button1? Can you please post the whole code and elaborate?

Comment: ur solution works fine for that case, but im asking for direct controls access for another needs such as i want to manage the content of multiple user controls from the form1

Comment: You can expose the properties from other forms and use them in form 1. 
You can also use events to set values
You can turn the controls public from designer 
There are many ways of doing this.

Comment: @FASTAYKO, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `string` property and use `Application.OpenForms` method to access the property.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

In form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
          
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("test4");
            testUcl1.Hide();
        }

        public string cmbtext
        {
            get
            {
                return comboBox1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                comboBox1.Text = value;
            }

        }
        bool t = true;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(t)
            {
                testUcl1.Show();
                t = !t;
            }
            else
            {
                testUcl1.Hide();
                t = !t;
            }
        }
    }
```

In Usercontrol:

```
public partial class TestUcl : UserControl
    {
        public TestUcl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            textBox1.Text = form1.cmbtext;
        }
    }
```

Test Result:

[image]